# Accessing native Android vector data for fonts?

Tags: android, svg, fonts, curve, bezier

I am working with vector images in Android and I need access to the actual glyph data. Like the Bezier curves that make up the font. Is there any way to access this data? I've debated converting fonts to SVG and reading those because I already have that ability. Or coding up a custom TTF parser. But, these solutions would also require a download or adding a bunch of extra TTF or SVG assets. And a perhaps a lot of work that might not be needed.

Is there some way to get access to the glyph data of a given font?

That failing, is there some way to get access to the actual ttf (or whatever font type Android uses) files?

[image: letter H]

I am working directly with vector images and manipulating the actual curves used to build vector images. Which means need actual access to the curves. Which curve goes where in order to build this particular letter. I don't want a bitmap or what harfbuzz within Android finally comes up with and pushes into GL, I want access to the actual curves used to make the font. Which means I can write my own font parser and include my own font assets, but all of that is built into Android but at the C level.

I would like to not have to include a font parser or a bunch of fonts. Android has both of those things included, are they just unreachable from the java level or is there perchance some trick?

I need the vector image from the font. Like the vector image of a letter A. The lines and curves used to build the letter. I don't need any of the kerning or em data, or missing glyphs info. And I'd like access to that without having to import an entire parser into my program and a bunch of font assets just to get the vector images the letters of the fonts are made out of.

Comment: You seem to be missing some crucial information here. Do you have SVG images (not just vector - there are many formats) with embedded text that use custom font rules, and you want access to the glyph data for those fonts? (If so, yes, you'll need a font parser like [opentypjs](https://nodebox.github.io/opentype.js) or [fontkit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fontkit). If not: There's information missing between "*I am working with vector images*" and "*I need access to the actual glyph data*" that is crucially important to answering this question.

Comment: Can you first please explain the missing details? If you work with plain vector images, those don't *have* glyph data, they're just vector images. Please explain what you are working with specifically, ideally with a reduced minimal example of the kind of file you're working with, that leads you to conclude there are "glyphs" that can be extracted. You're talking about curves that "make up the font", but what is "the" font, where does it come from? Are the "vector images" actually SVG fonts? Are they SVG with text that is styled with CSS loaded fonts? Please explain what you're doing.

Comment: Please put those answers in your question as question details (and then delete the comments). They're not going to help anyone be able to answer you if they first have to read a comment thread to find out the details of your question.

Comment: As someone who is extremely familiar with fonts, having written parsers for them, and many articles about them: a modern font is most certainly not what you describe. If you just have a vector image, and the lettering is just vector paths, then that image is not using "a font" in the slightest, and it does not encode "glyphs". It's just a vector image, and it can tell you nothing about what's in it. In the same way that a vector image with a car doesn't magically let you ask for the car brand or model. You need metadata, a thing fonts have in abundance, and vector images don't.

Comment: Take a look at this class : https://github.com/romannurik/muzei/blob/master/main/src/main/java/com/google/android/apps/muzei/util/AnimatedMuzeiLoadingSpinnerView.java

Comment: Looked promising but the important bit is LogoPaths.GLYPHS[0] which isn't an actual thing it's a custom setup path data thing, not something to grab that data from an actual font. It's totally there though and exactly the stuff I kind of want. But, not really font data just a static asset in a kinda obscure package. http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android_Free_Code/Development/studio/com_google_android_apps_muzei_utilLogoPaths_java.htm

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution for your requirement. Please read on.

Fonts are mostly outlines only. That is say in the letter "H" in your post above the dotted line is the path of the glyph. If you give a color to the strokes then you see the outline of the letter in that color. If you fill it then the letter appears in that color solidly.

You can use "font editor" of fontforge organisation to get the path data. The software of fontforge is freeware.(They accept donations). If you want center-line and not outline then you have to draw the centre-line and then export it as SVG file. You will be exporting single letter at a time. You can open the SVG file in wordpad and take the pathdata of your centre-line. However curved the glyph is you can easily draw the centre-line. Sometimes you can even improve the shape of the glyph in your centre-line. If it is centre-line then the strokes when you draw again will be  of uniform thickness. Not like the original glyph with gradually varying thickness of the line(centre-line). You can master the font editor just in a couple of days.

See the glyph below. Copy and paste the code below in an xml file in Android Studio and see the glyph drawn in blue color.That is centreline of thickness 32dp and not outline and fill.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="600dp"
        android:height="600dp"
        android:viewportWidth="800.0"
        android:viewportHeight="800.0">

    <path
        android:pathData="M  162   8
        q    -07    00   -41    26
        q    -34    27   -50    64
        q    -25    59   -19   117
        q     07    70    53   121
        q     57    63   151    62
        q     87   -01   140   -66
        q     46   -55    48  -142
        q     01   -56   -34  -105
        q    -38   -52   -77   -70
        l    -29   -11
        q     16   -01    31   -02
        q     59   -01   119   -02  "

        android:strokeLineCap="round"
        android:strokeColor="#f00f"
        android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:strokeWidth="32"/>



</vector>
```

Comment: I tended away from those because they require a bunch of assets I shouldn't need. While I could do each letter, there's a lot of fonts and a lot of letters and I want the glyph data without needing to download several megs of glyph data. There's a new bit in drawable that might work and fontdownloader etc but it's not got a compatibility bit yet.